Failed to send SQS message for ECS container without any error description
I have code running inside ECS container, with the following code to send SQS message:
import { SQSClient, SendMessageCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-sqs";

import { MAX_ATTEMPTS } from "./constants/sqs.js";
import type { SqsMessageBody } from "./types/sqs.js";

const sqsClient = new SQSClient({
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
    maxAttempts: MAX_ATTEMPTS,
    credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    },
});

const sqsMessageBody: SqsMessageBody = {
    endpointPath,
    endpointRoute,
    payload,
    requestId,
    transformationIssues,
};

const sendMessageSqsCommand = new SendMessageCommand({
    QueueUrl: process.env.SQS_URL_TRANSFORMATIONS_ALERT,
    MessageBody: JSON.stringify(sqsMessageBody),
});

await sqsClient.send(sendMessageSqsCommand);

When I run this code inside my ECS container, I also have a logger (it logs when the code above THROWS an error:
this.logger.warn("Failed to alert transformation issue", { error });
Then I try to run the first code block but it fails with error:

The error is thrown by the command sqsClient.send(...)
But the error is completely "empty" (without any AWS Request ID or message...)
The ECS container has this policy as well:

I have no idea how can I debug such thing. Also, note, that when I run dummy NodeJS script from my computer, sending dummy message to this SQS message it succeeds - the message is sent successfully

Where do the properties for the SQS payload come from? E.g. transformationIssues. The error message suggests, that there's maybe a problem constructing this.

I'm not sure why the fact it is running in ECS is relevant. Does the error only occur on ECS, or does it also occur when you run the same docker image locally? Also, have you added print/log statements for all the variables to verify they contain the values you think they do?
